# How to select a random tmx map to be loaded? Opening a random file in pygame?

Tags: python, random, pygame

Trying to select a random map from my maps folder when certain conditions are met, how would I go about selecting a new map.

```
MAP = ['map.tmx', 'map2.tmx', 'map3.tmx']

self.map_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'maps')
self.map = TiledMap(path.join(self.map_folder, MAP))

class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
        self.width = tm.width * tm.tilewidth
        self.height = tm.height * tm.tileheight
        self.tmxdata = tm

    def render(self, surface):
        ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x, y, gid, in layer:
                    tile = ti(gid)
                    if tile:
                        surface.blit(tile, (x * self.tmxdata.tilewidth,
                                            y * self.tmxdata.tileheight))

    def make_map(self):
        surface = py.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.render(surface)
        return surface
```

Comment: `map = random.choice(MAP)` - but it would need to remove used map to skip it in next choice(). So maybe first shuffle maps `random.shuffle(MAP)` and later use normally `for map in MAP:` - it will get in random order because `MAP` already have items in random order.

Comment: @furas that's worked thank you, just one last thing what if I want to always start on the same map. So load in the same map everytime how if a condition happens then load a random map?

Comment: you can use `MAP[0]` and `MAP[1:]` to create new list - as first element use `MAP[0]` and add elements from shuffled list `MAP[1:]`

Comment: Excellent thank you.

Comment: I added in answer example code which shuffles only MAP[1:] and keeps MAP[0] always as first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get something random you need module `random`

You can use `choice()` to get random item from list

```
import random

MAP = ['map.tmx', 'map2.tmx', 'map3.tmx']

map = random.choice(MAP)

print(map)
```

But if you use again `choice()` then sometimes you may get the same map. To get different map you would have to remove already used map from `MAP` before next `choice()`

OR you can do this in different way. Using `shuffle()` you get list with items in random order and then you can use `for`-loop to get always unique and random map

```
import random

MAP = ['map.tmx', 'map2.tmx', 'map3.tmx']

random.shuffle(MAP)

for map in MAPS:
    print(map)
```

---

**EDIT:** to keep first map always as first and shuffle only other maps

```
import random

MAP = ['map.tmx', 'map2.tmx', 'map3.tmx', 'map4.tmx', 'map5.tmx']

first = MAP[:1]  # list with one element - it need `first + rest` instead of `[first] + rest`
rest  = MAP[1:]
random.shuffle(rest)

MAP = first + rest

print(MAP)
```

**BTW:** in the same way you can keep first and second map in place

```
first = MAP[:2]
rest  = MAP[2:]
```

---

**EDIT:** After shuffling

To load only first map

```
map = MAP[0]
fullpath = path.join(self.map_folder, map)
self.map = TiledMap(fullpath)
```

To work with all maps you may run in loop

```
for map in MAP:

    fullpath = path.join(self.map_folder, map)
    self.map = TiledMap(fullpath)

    # ... run game with this map ...
```

OR use variable with `level`

```
# first level 

level = 0

map = MAP[level]
fullpath = path.join(self.map_folder, map)
self.map = TiledMap(fullpath)

# ... run game with this map ...

# next level 

level += 1

map = MAP[level]
fullpath = path.join(self.map_folder, map)
self.map = TiledMap(fullpath)

# ... run game with this map ...

# next level 

level += 1

map = MAP[level]
fullpath = path.join(self.map_folder, map)
self.map = TiledMap(fullpath)

# ... run game with this map ...

# etc.
```

Comment: I'm getting a **TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'** because of the line `self.map = TiledMap(path.join(self.map_folder, MAP))`

Comment: `MAP` is a list but you have to get one element from list. ie. `path.join(..., random.choice(MAP))`

Comment: I understand the principle behind random module, I get why you'd shuffle rest then put the 2 lists together however, I don't understand why use `TiledMap(path.join(self.map_folder, random.choice(MAP)))`. This results in a random map being loaded everytime you start the program not the first in the list.

Comment: it is only example that you can't use `MAP` because it is list - you have to get element from list `map = ...` and use this element - `join(self.map_folder, map)`. And in example I used `map = random.choice(MAP)` but normally you can use `map = MAP[0]` to get first map or you has to run it in loop `for map in MAP: load_map_play_game_etc`

Comment: Awesome! It worked, I had an issue with the indexing once it reached the last level but I resolved that in the end :) thank you very much you been a massive help